# When initialising member with temporary, how to ensure a single call to temporary's constructor?

Tags: c++, move

Suppose I have a wrapper:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Outer {
    T inner;
    ...
};
```

, and I want to create an `Outer` wrapping an `Inner`, like so:

```cpp
Outer<Inner> wrapper(Inner(...)); // Inner object is a temporary
```

Is it possible to declare `Outer`/`Inner` such that creating an `Outer` object from a temporary `Inner` involves the construction of only a single `Inner` object? I tried declaring the move constructor for `Inner`, and having `Outer` take an rvalue reference to `Inner`, and even explicitly calling `std::move` on the temporary, but still, 2 copies of `Inner` are created:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct Outer {
    T inner;
    Outer(T&& inner) : inner(inner) {}
};

struct Inner {
    int x;
    int y;

    Inner(const int x, const int y) : x(x), y(y) { printf("ctor\n"); }
    Inner(const Inner& rhs) : x(rhs.x), y(rhs.y) { printf("copy ctor\n"); }
    Inner(Inner&& rhs) : x(std::exchange(rhs.x, 0)), y(std::exchange(rhs.y, 0)) {
        printf("move ctor\n");
    }
    Inner& operator=(const Inner& rhs) { 
        printf("assign\n"); 
        return *this = Inner(rhs); 
    }
    Inner& operator=(Inner&& rhs) { 
        printf("move assign\n");
        std::swap(x, rhs.x);
        std::swap(y, rhs.y);
        return *this;
    }
    ~Inner() { printf("dtor\n"); }
};

int main() {
    Outer<Inner> wrapper(Inner(123, 234));
    // SAME: Outer<Inner> wrapper(std::move(Inner(123, 234)));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ctor <-- The temporary
copy ctor <-- Yet another instance, from the temporary
dtor
dtor
```

As shown above, the creation of an `Outer` instance creates 2 `Inners`. This seems strange as I thought the temporary can be elided, or at least, invoke the move constructor. Is it possible to instantiate `Outer` with a single `Inner` construction?

Comment: You need `inner(std::move(inner))` in the move constructor. (And lose the `const`. Moving is expected to modify the moved-from object.)

Comment: It's still the same behaviour with std::move (and doing without the const)

Comment: No, it prints "move ctor", as it should.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't for me. I also tried other C++ repls online (replit, godbolt), doesn't print move ctor. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @moog. https://godbolt.org/z/3aWY9hfse

Comment: Ah, thank you molbdnilo and @康桓瑋: I misunderstood and was using std::move in the wrong place.

Comment: @康桓瑋
Is it possible to go one step further to construct inner member "in-place" via the temporary? i.e. not even the move ctor, just the temporary's ctor.

Comment: @moog With these particular classes, that should be the case if you remove everything except the member variables and let the compiler do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct Outer {
    T inner;
    // Outer(T &&inner) : inner(std::move(inner)) {}
    template <class... Args> Outer(Args &&...args) :inner(args...) {}
};

struct Inner {
    int x;
    int y;

    Inner(const int x, const int y) : x(x), y(y) { printf("ctor\n"); }
    Inner(const Inner &rhs) : x(rhs.x), y(rhs.y) { printf("copy ctor\n"); }
    Inner(Inner &&rhs)
        : x(std::exchange(rhs.x, 0)), y(std::exchange(rhs.y, 0)) {
        printf("move ctor\n");
    }
    Inner &operator=(const Inner &rhs) {
        printf("assign\n");
        return *this = Inner(rhs);
    }
    Inner &operator=(Inner &&rhs) {
        printf("move assign\n");
        std::swap(x, rhs.x);
        std::swap(y, rhs.y);
        return *this;
    }
    ~Inner() { printf("dtor\n"); }
};

int main() {
    Outer<Inner> wrapper(123, 234);
    // SAME: Outer<Inner> wrapper(std::move(Inner(123, 234)));
    return 0;
}
```